# Sencha Theme Customization Issue

Tags: extjs, rubygems, sencha-touch-2, sass, compass-sass

I started learning sencha touch 2.2.1. I am facing problems in creating custom SASS files (or creating custom theme files) for my app. I created a custom.scss file in resources/sass directory. In custom.scss file I paste this mixin:

```
@include sencha-toolbar-ui('sub', #58710D, 'glossy');
```

and import my custom.scss file in app.scss, and then i ran a terminal command: compass compile for 'resources/sass' but it threw an error:

```
C:\AppServ\www\gs\resources>compass compile
error sass/app.scss (Line 5: File to import not found or unreadable: sencha-  touch/default.
 Load paths:

    C:/AppServ/www/gs/resources/sass
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                      Compass::SpriteImporter)
                      identical stylesheets/app.css
                      error sass/custom.scss (Line 1: Undefined mixin 'sencha-toolbar-ui'.)
                      overwrite stylesheets/custom.css
```

Also I want to ask another thing, i have looked over many of the apps customized sass files. But I could not understand one thing in common. In app.scss, i saw many of times this code. I guess they are mixins but when I copy/paste them in my app.scss, i got an error saying: undefined @mixins sencha-panel.

```
 @include sencha-panel;   
 @include sencha-buttons;
 @include sencha-sheet;
 @include sencha-picker;
 @include sencha-tabs;
 @include sencha-toolbar;
 @include sencha-toolbar-forms;
 @include sencha-indexbar;
 @include sencha-list;
 @include sencha-layout;
 @include sencha-carousel;
 @include sencha-form;
 @include sencha-msgbox;
```

Kindly help me and if you can share any links regarding how can i create my own sass file in sencha, then i will be gratefull to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ST 2.0 you don't use "@include sencha-panel ..." anymore. You have to use "@import ...". See the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/guide/theming